# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \frac{4n^2+1}{4n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm stuck with the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \frac{4n^2+1}{4n^2}$$

It appears to converge, however I've not been able to prove it. Any clues?

Also, provided the convergence, any method to compute the sum?

Comment: Hint for convergence: Recall $\log(1 + \epsilon) \sim \epsilon$. As far as actually computing the sum, I'm not sure

Comment: What have you tried? It helps to show your efforts.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Now I see it. Using that, one obtains directly the convergence by the limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n^2}$. Thank you!

Comment: @VarunVejalla I tried to simplificate it, to write it like a telescopic sum/product, the ratio test, root test, direct comparison test... but I didn't manage to make any of these methods work. Now it seems obvious to me that the easiest way was to use the infinitesimal and the LCT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \frac{4n^2+1}{4n^2}$$
$$e^{S} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left (1+\frac{1}{4n^2} \right )$$
$$e^{-S} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left (\frac{4n^2}{1+4n^2} \right )$$
Notice that $$\frac{\pi}{2} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left (\frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1} \right ),$$
this is the famous [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).
So the product stemming from your equation must converge since the denominator of the product for $e^{-S}$ is bigger. Hence your sum is convergent.

The Wallis product is a specific case of $$ \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left (1-\frac{z^{2}}{n^{2}} \right )$$

so just pick $z = \frac{i}{2}$ to get the answer.

Comment: To unbury the lede... the final result is $S = \log(\frac{2 \sinh(\pi / 2)}{\pi})$.

Comment: What a beautiful solution. Thank you!

Comment: @franciscoJácomeMaura You should try proving the general product formula. Look up the way Euler discovered it.

Answer (score 2):

Just for convergence,
this elementary inequality
is enough:

For $z > 0$,
$\dfrac1{z+1}
\lt \ln(1+\frac1{z})
\lt \dfrac1{z}
$.

Then,
since

$\log \frac{4n^2+1}{4n^2}
=\log(1+\frac1{4n^2})
\lt \frac1{4n^2}
$,
the sum of these converges.

Here is the elementary proof
of the inequality.

For $x > 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(1+x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}\\
&\lt\int_0^x dt\\
&= x\\
\text{and}\\
\ln(1+x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}\\
&\gt\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+x}\\
&= \dfrac{x}{1+x}\\
\text{so}\\
\ln(1+\frac1{z})
&> \dfrac{1/z}{1+1/z}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{z+1}\\
\end{array}
$

For this problem
you do not need the
second inequality,
but it useful when
you want to prove divergence.

Comment: I think you need to mention that the sum of inverse squares converges (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: That's pretty easy - they should be able to do that themselves.